# Entering ! (exclamation sign) in the OBLIGATORY parameter doesn't work as input. Why?

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

Suppose we have following selection screen:

```
PARAMETERS: d_char OBLIGATORY.

WRITE d_char.
```

When the user enters `!` in this field of selection-screen and runs the program, it still prompts for required entry in this field.

Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the answer in the documentation for [Dynpro Fields](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/abenabap_dynpros_fields.htm).

> When dynpro fields are received from input fields on the screen, input fields are templates that expect a certain format depending on the data type of the underlying dynpro field. When passed to the dynpro field, the input is converted to a value of the appropriate type. This also means that some characters function as special characters by default.
>
> **The "!" character in the initial position of an input field on the screen deletes all characters in the field before the data transport.**
>
> The "=" character in the initial position of an input field on the screen initiates a search using search helps.
>
> If an input field contains only blanks and "_" characters, the latter are transported as blanks.
>
> To deactivate the template and also the modifying effect of special characters, the attribute Without Template can be activated in Screen Painter. However, the template **cannot be deactivated for selection screens**.

Answer (score 0):

Define the parameter as TYPE STRING and you will receive the ! as well as the = or even a space.